# Recursively deny access but allow access via htpasswd to 1 file in subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm currently denying access to all subdirectories and files with exception to the file  `/var/www/subdir/file.php`

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>

<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Location>
```

How can I protect this file with `htpasswd`?  I tried the following syntax, but it did not work:

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>

<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Access"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/private_html/passwords/allowed-users
      Require user me
</Location>
```

**EDIT**
Here's my entire `httpd.conf` file

```
<Directory /var/www/public_html/*>
        Allow from None
        Order allow,deny
</Directory>

<Location /hello1.php>

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Access"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/private_html/passwords/allowed-users
        Require user me

        SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/hello1.php)$" allow

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from env=allow
        Satisfy any

</Location>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior it was exhibiting when it didn't work?

Comment: It allowed access to the the file from the URL without prompting for password validation

Comment: Do you have a `Satisfy any` directive somewhere else in your configuration?

Comment: No - All I have is the code block that says 
`<Directory /var/www/public_html/*>
        Allow from None
        Order allow,deny
</Directory>`

Comment: I mean anywhere else in your Apache configuration that would apply to this request.  It doesn't need to be in the same file.

Comment: No - I just did a grep -ir 'Satisfy any' and it only shows up in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Yes, `httpd.conf` is most certainly part of your configuration.  Please provide the relevant section of the config in your question.  What file are these directives in, by the way?

Comment: Shane I'm going to put my complete httpd.conf in an Edit to the original post, give me 30 seconds

Comment: Oh - it looks like that section for hello1.php is just a test of the config provided in NiteRain's answer?

Comment: No that's a file I created `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` that I try to access from `mysite.com/hello.php`.  I would like for it to prompt me for password.

Comment: Try removing the `Allow from env=allow` from your test config, and leave the rest the same.  That ought to work.. something else is going on if it doesn't.

Comment: Shane I tried that but it did not work =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <FilesMatch "^(?!protected\.html)$">
       deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
    <Files "protected.html">
       AuthName "Username and password required"
       AuthUserFile /www/sites/testcase.com/.htpasswd
       Require valid-user
       AuthType Basic
    </Files>
```

You will get a forbidden for everything but the file in question.  But when you try to access protected.html or whatever name you want, it will give you a basic authentication dialog.

Answer (score 2):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/file\.php)$"  allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

You can put the above in your .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Try denying access by IP address.  This should work around `satisfy any`, but no access would be allowed with `satisfy all`.

```
<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      deny from all

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Access"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/private_html/passwords/allowed-users
      Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Or try using satisfy any to require password from untrusted addresses.

```
<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from 127.0.0.1
      deny from all
      satisfy any

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Access"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/private_html/passwords/allowed-users
      Require user me
</Location>
```

Check your error log to see if anything is logged there.  I have found the solution there in a few cases where I got directives wrong.